# Cancel button in overlay doesn't work ti.barcode

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, barcode-scanner

I've been using ti.barcode 1.9.1 in my iOS app with titanium appcelerator 3.5
Everything is working fine except for one thing
the cancel button doesn't work on the device.

But in simulation works perfectly.

I'm using a model view controller architecture in my project using Titanium Classic

Here is the class that manage all functions related to the barcode scanner

```js
//historial de productos escaneados
var scannedBarcodes = {}; 
var scannedBarcodesCount = 0;

 //creacion de objeto Barcode
var Barcode = require('ti.barcode');
Barcode.allowRotation = true;
Barcode.displayedMessage = '';
Barcode.useLED = false;
 
//vista transparente que muestra lo que procesa la camara
var overlay = Ti.UI.createView({
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
 top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0
});
 
 //boton cancelar para cerrar la vista
var cancelButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
 title: '  '+L('generales_cancelar')+'  ', 
 color: Ti.App.COLOR_TINTE, 
 backgroundColor: Ti.App.COLOR_BOTON,
 font: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 },
 borderRadius: 5,
 width: 120, height: 30,
 bottom: 20
});
 
//accionador de cerrar la vista de lectura de codigos
cancelButton.addEventListener('touchend', function () { 
 Barcode.cancel(); 
});
overlay.add(cancelButton);
 
//funcion que manda activar el lector de codigo de barras 
//parametro keepOpen en falso para cerrar y procesar lo leido una vez capturado
var callScanner = function(){
  
 reset();
 // Note: while the simulator will NOT show a camera stream in the simulator, you may still call "Barcode.capture"
 // to test your barcode scanning overlay.
 Barcode.capture({
  animate: true,
  overlay: this.overlay,
  showCancel: false,
  showRectangle: true,
  keepOpen: false/*,
  acceptedFormats: [
   Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE
  ]*/
 });
};
 
//funcion para resetear los valores del historico de objetos scaneados
var reset = function() {
 scannedBarcodes = {};
 scannedBarcodesCount = 0; 
};
 
 
Barcode.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
 
});
 
Barcode.addEventListener('cancel', function (e) {
  Ti.API.info('ejecutando cancel');
     Ti.API.info('Cancel received');     
});
 
Barcode.addEventListener('success', function (e) {
     Ti.API.info('Success called with barcode: ' + e.result);
});
```

In order to access to the barcode in my project I just have to use an include
in my upper bar file. Which is a menu that is present in the whole application

```js
var iconocodigobarras_viw = Ti.UI.createView({
 width:30, height:24, right:5,
 backgroundImage:'../Assets/Images/Icons/icon-codigobarras.png'
});
campobusqueda_viw.add(iconocodigobarras_viw);

Ti.include("../Includes/CodigoBarras_Inc.js");
```

And in order to call the scanner, in the implementation of my upperBarViewEvent I just call the function call scanner.

```js
iconocodigobarras_viw.addEventListener('touchend',function(){
 Ti.API.info('cargando scanner');
 //Ti.App.fireEvent("AbrirLibreAcceso");
 callScanner();
});
```

Like I said. I made it work with iPhone and iPad and it works just perfect. except that the Cancel button in the overlay doesn't work.

Does anyone is having the same trouble?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The example (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/master/ios/example/app.js) also has an overlay with a button. Does that example work for you on device? If it doesn't, then you've found a module bug that you can report on JIRA (http://jira.appcelerator.org). If it does work, then there's an error in your code and you should try to comment out as much as you can until it works and then re-enable step by step until you find what was causing it.

Comment: after further testing on my device and compile the example code I found that there is a bug in the overlay view and all buttons you place there either don't respond or take too much time to do it

Comment: You mean there's a bug in the module? OK, please see if there's a ticket on JIRA for that and if not, please report so we can get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I posted the ticket on JIRA and I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: hi, me getting same issue also. You found any solution?